# C++ - strange compile error with method template overloading and lambdas

Tags: c++

the following code, which can be compiled/run under onlinegdb.com produces very strange compile error. I know fix and it's included as commented, but would like to know an explanation for the compilation error. Code follows:

```
/******************************************************************************

Welcome to GDB Online.
GDB online is an online compiler and debugger tool for C, C++, Python, Java, PHP, Ruby, Perl,
C#, VB, Swift, Pascal, Fortran, Haskell, Objective-C, Assembly, HTML, CSS, JS, SQLite, Prolog.
Code, Compile, Run and Debug online from anywhere in world.

*******************************************************************************/
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


template <class It, class LessThanOp>
void createSortKey(It begin, It end, std::vector<int>& sortKey, LessThanOp lessThanOp)
{
  auto size = static_cast<int>(end - begin);
  sortKey.resize(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
      sortKey.at(i) = i;

    auto iteratorLessThan = [lessThanOp, begin](int first, int second)
    {
      return lessThanOp(begin[first], begin[second]);
    };

    std::sort(sortKey.begin(), sortKey.end(), iteratorLessThan);
}


template <class It>
void makeUniqueIndexKeyOnly(It begin, It end, std::vector<int>& uniqueMappingKey)
{
  auto equalOp = [](typename std::iterator_traits<It>::reference first, typename std::iterator_traits<It>::reference second) { return first == second; };
  auto lessThanOp = [](typename std::iterator_traits<It>::reference first, typename std::iterator_traits<It>::reference second) { return first < second; };
  makeUniqueIndexKeyOnly(begin, end, uniqueMappingKey, lessThanOp, equalOp);
}


template <class It, class LessThanOp>
void makeUniqueIndexKeyOnly(It begin, It end, std::vector<int>& uniqueMappingKey, LessThanOp lessThanOp)
{
  // Note that we have to create equal operator from less than operator since less than operator maybe custom defined
    auto equalOp = [lessThanOp](auto& first, auto& second)
    {
      return !lessThanOp(first, second) && !lessThanOp(second, first);
    };   
    makeUniqueIndexKeyOnly(begin, end, uniqueMappingKey, lessThanOp, equalOp);
}

template <class It, class LessThanOp, class EqualOp>
void makeUniqueIndexKeyOnly(It begin, It end, std::vector<int>& uniqueMappingKey, LessThanOp lessThanOp, EqualOp equalOp)
{
    std::vector<int> sortKey;
    createSortKey(begin, end, sortKey, lessThanOp); // Does compile error
    makeUniqueIndexKeyOnly(begin, end, sortKey, uniqueMappingKey, equalOp); // Does compile error
    
    //createSortKey<It, LessThanOp>(begin, end, sortKey, lessThanOp); // Following code fixes the error
    //makeUniqueIndexKeyOnly<It, EqualOp>(begin, end, sortKey, uniqueMappingKey, equalOp); // Following code fixes the error
}

template <class It>
void makeUniqueIndexKeyOnly(It begin, It end, const std::vector<int>& sortKey, std::vector<int>& uniqueMappingKey)
{
  auto equalOp = [](typename std::iterator_traits<It>::reference first, typename std::iterator_traits<It>::reference second) { return first == second; };
  makeUniqueIndexKeyOnly(begin, end, sortKey, uniqueMappingKey, equalOp);  
}

template <class It, class EqualOp>
void makeUniqueIndexKeyOnly(It begin, It end, const std::vector<int>& sortKey, std::vector<int>& uniqueMappingKey, EqualOp equalOp)
{
  // Here the code for making the unique index array would come - code not neccessary for this compile error problem
}


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a;
    a.push_back(2);
    a.push_back(3);
    
    std::vector<int> uniqueMappingKey;
    makeUniqueIndexKeyOnly(a.begin(), a.end(), uniqueMappingKey);

    return 0;
}
```

The error it creates and I don't understand is that it somehow starts passing std::vector type instead of lambda for LessThanOp.
Error follows:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘createSortKey(It, It, std::vector<int>&, LessThanOp)::<lambda(int, int)> [with It = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; LessThanOp = std::vector<int>]’:
<span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.cpp',22)">main.cpp:22:42</span>:   required from ‘struct createSortKey(It, It, std::vector<int>&, LessThanOp) [with It = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; LessThanOp = std::vector<int>]::<lambda(int, int)>’
<span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.cpp',22)">main.cpp:22:10</span>:   required from ‘void createSortKey(It, It, std::vector<int>&, LessThanOp) [with It = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; LessThanOp = std::vector<int>]’
<span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.cpp',55)">main.cpp:55:18</span>:   required from ‘void makeUniqueIndexKeyOnly(It, It, std::vector<int>&, LessThanOp, EqualOp) [with It = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; LessThanOp = std::vector<int>; EqualOp = makeUniqueIndexKeyOnly(It, It, std::vector<int>&) [with It = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >]::<lambda(std::__iterator_traits<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, void>::reference, std::__iterator_traits<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, void>::reference)>]’
<span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.cpp',56)">main.cpp:56:27</span>:   required from ‘void makeUniqueIndexKeyOnly(It, It, std::vector<int>&, LessThanOp, EqualOp) [with It = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; LessThanOp = makeUniqueIndexKeyOnly(It, It, std::vector<int>&) [with It = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >]::<lambda(std::__iterator_traits<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, void>::reference, std::__iterator_traits<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, void>::reference)>; EqualOp = makeUniqueIndexKeyOnly(It, It, std::vector<int>&) [with It = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >]::<lambda(std::__iterator_traits<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, void>::reference, std::__iterator_traits<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, void>::reference)>]’
<span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.cpp',36)">main.cpp:36:25</span>:   required from ‘void makeUniqueIndexKeyOnly(It, It, std::vector<int>&) [with It = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >]’
<span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.cpp',85)">main.cpp:85:64</span>:   required from here
main.cpp:24:24: error: no match for call to ‘(const std::vector) (int&, int&)’
       return lessThanOp(begin[first], begin[second]);
              ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Please add the specific compiler version as well as the exact compiler flags used to your question. You uncovered a bug in the template argument type deduction logic, but whether you are even on a recent version of the compiler is an open question.

Comment: In the line `makeUniqueIndexKeyOnly(begin, end, sortKey, uniqueMappingKey, equalOp); // Does compile error` which overload of `makeUniqueIndexKeyOnly` do you expect to be called? Unfortunately you have two overloads that accept 5 arguments...

Comment: The version from onlinegdb.com is g++-7 7.4.0 c++17. I can also tell that it errors on VS2017 as well. Don't know about newer versions.

Comment: Yes, there are 2 overloads with 5 arguments, but the second overload is of signature (It, It, const std::vector<int>&, std::vector<int>&, EqualOp) - 4th argument is std::vector<int>& onto which I don't think lambda is convertible. So this overload is not called - as seen from error trace as well.

Comment: @PavelCelba The fourth argument is `uniqueMappingKey` and it seems that you _want_ that overload to be selected, but that isn't happening as you noticed.

Comment: @user17732522 Yes, correct sorry, but even for createSortKey it passes instead LessThanOp lambda std::vector<int> on line before.

Comment: @PavelCelba No, that happens only because you recursively call the same `makeUniqueIndexKeyOnly` overload again and the second time the `LessThanOp` type is wrong, resulting in the call to `createSortKey` not working correctly. You managed to make the overload that you want to prefer a worse match by having its `sortKey` marked `const`, but the other overload's parameter `uniqueMappingKey` in the same position _not_ be marked `const`. Change that and it will compile (although that overload structure seems too fragile to begin with and you also have some potential declaration ordering issues).

Comment: Hmm, correct. So the problem is std::vector<int> (for uniqueMappingKey) is closer match to LessThanOp template parameter. Because the other overload is of type std::vector<int>& (REFERENCE!) and therefore not as close match. Thanks!!! Not a C++ bug.